# Charm-Crypto: Got <terminated, exit value: 139> when trying to serialize object

Tags: python, encryption, serialization, charm-crypto

I'm implementing a [Dabe scheme](https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/charm/schemes/dabe_aw11.html) with [Charm](http://charm-crypto.com/) and I need to share the public parameters over multiple entities. I'm trying to serialize the charm object containing these parameters using **objectToBytes**() function in the serialization API that come with Charm but I got my script terminated with exit code 139.
Here's my code:

```
from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import PairingGroup,ZR,G1,G2,GT,pair
from charm.toolbox.secretutil import SecretUtil
from charm.toolbox.ABEncMultiAuth import ABEncMultiAuth
from charm.core.engine.util import objectToBytes, bytesToObject
from charm.core.math.pairing import hashPair as extractor
from charm.schemes.dabe_aw11 import Dabe

# Global Setup
group = PairingGroup('SS512')
dabe = Dabe(group)
public_parameters = dabe.setup()  # GP

# Trying to serialize public_parameters but...
# ...the following instruction causes the script <terminated, exit value: 139>
GP = objectToBytes(public_parameters, group)
```

I have run debug mode in Eclipse and stepped into my code, the problem seems to be in the **serialize**() function present in `PairingGroup` class definition which returns the **serialize**() (compiled) function as imported from `charm.core.math.pairing`.

Anybody has encountered this problem before? Any suggestions on how could be possible to use (import) charm objects over multiple scripts?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The GP or public_parameters is a dictionary composed of 'g', which is a pairing.Element object, and 'H', which is a lambda mapping to a hash function (the random oracle). It might be the case that the objectToBytes and subsequent functions are attempting to serialize the lambda mapping and causing the error.

I have tested the PairingGroup.serialize() function and it does work for pairing.Element objects. The 'g' value is actually the only one you need to share, in my understanding. The 'H' is just a hash mapping within a fixed group:  in Charm's case, it is always H = lambda x: group.hash(x, G1) for dabe_aw11.py, wherein G1 comes from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup. Therefore, you can always define the lambda mapping and add the constant, shared 'g', or just call setup() (which chooses a 'g' and defines the 'H' mapping) and substitute the 'g' for the previously chosen/shared one. The goal is to just serialize the 'g' from the public_parameters dictionary, skipping the 'H' in there.

This is the option I am attempting here in a proof-of-concept for a Ph.D. dissertation that utilizes dabe_aw11.